# Constructor call in composition

Tags: c++, composition

I have the following code for composition. It generates an error,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X
{
      private:
              int iX;
      public:
             X(int i=0) : iX(i) { cout <<"Constructing X.."<<endl; } 
             ~X() { cout <<"Destructing X.."<<endl; }

             int getIX() { return iX; } 
};

class Y
{
      private:
              X x(3);
              int jY;
      public:
             Y(int j = 0) : jY(j) { cout <<"Constructing Y.."<<endl; }
             ~Y() { cout <<"Destructing Y.."<<endl; }
             void callGetX() { cout <<"iX is "<<(x.getIX())<<endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Y yObj(1);
    yObj.callGetX();
}
```

Error:
In member Function void Y::callGetX()
'x' undeclared (first use this function)

Is there anything that i have missed? 
Can anyone please tell me the constructor call mechanism for this scenario?

Comment: What error are you getting? This is perfectly valid: `X x(5);`.

Comment: This is not related to your problems, but `#include <iostream>` instead `#include "iostream"`

Comment: It says, 
In member function voidY::callGetX() 
x undeclared (first use this function)

Comment: @RajeevMehta that seems like a different issue. Why don't you just post the code that generates the error?

Comment: It works fine for me if I initialize `x` in the member initializers: `Y(int j = 0) : x(5), jY(j){...}` The errors start happening when I say `X x(5);` in the class itself (which is what I presume you were trying to do).

Comment: @Chris - Yes i was trying to create an instance as X x(3) as you mentioned. I made the change and it works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
X x(3);
```

This is not legal in C++ (legal in Java AFAIK). In fact it makes the compiler think that `x` is a member function that returns an object of class `X` instead of considering `x` a member variable of class `X`.

Instead do this:

```
Y(int j = 0) : jY(j), x(3) { cout <<"Constructing Y.."<<endl; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You put the member in your initialization list:

```
Y(int j = 0) : x(3), jY(j)
```

Your syntax:

```
class Y
{
private:
   X x(3);
//...
};
```

is illegal.